# DocuSign: Get a response when document is signed/completed

Tags: docusignapi

So I'm using REST API for my DocuSign handling, and I have this snippet that checks every 30 mins the status of each envelope, but I'm having hard time find out if there is a way to trigger response (i.e. email) as soon as someone signs the document?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the DocuSign REST API includes a webhook facility that you can use. When you call Envelopes:Create, include an `eventNotification` object. In that object you include an internet-accessible URL.

The DocuSign platform will then make HTTPS POSTS to your URL when there is an interesting status change to your envelope. (You define "interesting" status changes as part of the eventNotification object.)

See the [eventNotification](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope.htm) section in the docs.